# Insert data on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm starting with programming, and I have questions.
First, I can insert data on firebase, but, when I try to insert new data, this data inserted before is changed/updated to new data. How can I insert new data and continue with before data?
Second, how can I insert data on firebase together "primary key"? (example in image).
["Primary key" highlighted in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XH91.png)
Hugs.

Comment: you want to use `push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 mDatabase.child("tasks").push().setValue(firebaseData, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            //Problem with saving the data
            if (databaseError != null) {

            } else {
                //Data uploaded successfully on the server

               }

            }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer solved my problem :) +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

A Firebase database is structured as pairs, of key and values. This means that every node in the database is a `Map`. When you add data to Firebase, think that you are adding data to a `Map`. As we know, a `Map` does not allow duplicate keys. This means that if we use the same key, in the case of `Map`, **it replaces the old value with the new one**. This means that every time we want to add data, we need a different key. The practice in Firebase is to use the `push()` method, which provides a unique key every time the method is called.

To add data to your Firebase database, i recomand you using the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tasksRef = rootRef.child("tasks").push();
tasksRef.setValue(taskObject);
```

You can also add `CompletionListener` to actually see if the data was successfully added into the database.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer solved my problem :) +1 for you.